# Python Sending command

Tags: python

I'm trying to send a End command to the end of this line of code.
I've searched everywhere and not able to find a valuable answer..

```
if args.time:
    def stopwatch(seconds):
        start = time.time()
        time.clock()    
        elapsed = 0
        while elapsed < seconds:
            elapsed = time.time() - start
            print "Sending for(900) Seconds: %f, seconds count: %02d" % (time.clock() , elapsed) 
            time.sleep(1)  

stopwatch(5)
```

Wanting to send a `Control C` of some sort here to stop it without 
Exiting the program.

Answer (score 1):

You want to catch a `KeyboardInterrupt`:

```
if args.time:
    def stopwatch(seconds):
        start = time.time()
        time.clock()    
        elapsed = 0
        while elapsed < seconds:
            try:
                elapsed = time.time() - start
                print "Sending for(900) Seconds: %f, seconds count: %02d" % (time.clock() , elapsed) 
                time.sleep(1)  
            except KeyboardInterrupt: break

    stopwatch(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use control-c.

You just have to catch the **KeyboardInterrupt** Exception.

```
try:
    # your loop code here
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # do whatever you want when user presses ctrl+c
```